# Spark on YARN too less vcores used

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, resource-management

I'm using Spark in a YARN cluster (HDP 2.4) with the following settings:

- 1 Masternode

  - 64 GB RAM (50 GB usable)
  - 24 cores (19 cores usable)
- 5 Slavenodes

  - 64 GB RAM (50 GB usable) each
  - 24 cores (19 cores usable) each
- YARN settings

  - memory of all containers (of one host): 50 GB
  - minimum container size = 2 GB
  - maximum container size = 50 GB
  - vcores = 19
  - minimum #vcores/container = 1
  - maximum #vcores/container = 19

When I run my spark application with the command `spark-submit --num-executors 30 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 7g --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 1800m ...` YARN creates 31 containers (one for each executor process + one driver process) with the following settings:

- **Correct**: Master container with 1 core & ~1800 MB RAM
- **Correct**: 30 slave containers with ~7 GB RAM each
- **BUT INCORRECT**: each slave container only runs with **1 core** instead of 3, according to the YARN ResourceManager UI (it shows only 31 of 95 in use, instead of 91 = 30 * 3 + 1), see screenshot below

[image]

My question here: Why does the `spark-submit` parameter `--executor-cores 3` have no effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, seems to be the same issue as discussed here: [yarn is not honouring yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563736/yarn-is-not-honouring-yarn-nodemanager-resource-cpu-vcores/25570709#25570709) The solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using Ambari:

- Select YARN Queue Manager from top right corner
- Scheduler section
- Change "Calculator" drop-down to = "Dominant Resource"

Answer (score 0):

The UI could be misleading. When vcore enforcement is disabled in YARN, it will just assume one core per container, whereas in fact, if you look at the actual CPU usage of the physical machine, it could be using all of the cores. Also check the core usage on your SparkUI, that usually gives a better understanding of the actual CPU usage.