# VCores used is always less than VCores total in Spark on YARN on AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I'm using Spark to run a grid search job using spark sklearn package. Here's my config

```
NUM_SLAVES = 14
DRIVER_SPARK_MEMORY=53 # "spark.driver.memory"
EXECUTOR_SPARK_MEMORY=5 # "spark.executor.memory"
EXECUTOR_CORES=1 #"spark.executor.cores"
DRIVER_CORES=1 # "spark.driver.cores"
EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=126 # "spark.executor.instances"
SPARK_DYNAMICALLOCATION_ENABLED=false # "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"
SPARK_YARN_EXECUTOR_MEMORYOVERHEAD=1024 # "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead"
SPARK_YARN_DRIVER_MEMORYOVERHEAD=6144 # "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead"
SPARK_DEFAULT_PARALLELISM=252 # "spark.default.parallelism"
```

This is reflected in the configuration settings on AWS EMR
[image: This is reflected in the configuration settings on AWS EMR]

Each slave has 60 GB memory (c4.8xlarge) and the driver is the same machine. They have 36 VCPUs and I read on AWS that this means 18 cores. Based on this I've the above config that minimizes my unused memory.

[image: configuration from AWS]

The above picture shows the cluster metrics.

I dont know why just 43 cores out of 495 available are used, although the memory is used properly. I'm using the DominantResourceCalculator as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368985/spark-on-yarn-too-less-vcores-used).

Can someone suggest what am I missing here?