# Spark on Yarn Number of Cores in EMR Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have an Emr cluster for spark with below configuration of 2 Instances.

```
r4.2xlarge
8 vCore
```

So my total vCores is **16** and the same is reflected in yarn Vcores

I have submitted a spark streaming job with parameters --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 5. So I was assuming it will use up **2*5 total 10 vcores** for executors, but what it's doing only using 2 cores in total from the cluster (+1 for the driver)

.[image: yarn memory aloc]

And in spark, the job is still running with parallel tasks of 10 (2*5). Seems like it's just running only 5 threads within each executor core.
[image: tasks]

I have read in different questions and in documentation --executor-cores uses actual vCores but here, it only running tasks as threads.
Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: can you provide spark-submit command ... and what is the memory configurations you have given for driver and executor.. did you enabled dynamic allocation?

Comment: As you can see on yarn the allocation is constant..memory allocated 6g per executor and 4g for driver...there is nothing more in the spark submit command

Comment: Looks very similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368985/spark-on-yarn-too-less-vcores-used