# yarn allocate containers for Spark in AWS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I was able to create YARN containers for my spark jobs.
I have come across various blogs and youtube videos to efficiently use --executors-cores (use values from 4 -6 for efficient throughput) and --executor memory after reserving 1 CPU cores and 1GB RAM for hadoop deamons and determined the right values for each executor.

I also came across articles like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563736/yarn-is-not-honouring-yarn-nodemanager-resource-cpu-vcores/25570709#25570709).

I am checking how many containers are created by YARN from spark shell and i am not able to understand how the containers are allocated.

For example i have created EMR cluster with 1 master node m5.xlarge (4 vcore , 16 Gib) and 1 core node with instance type c5.2xlarge ( 8 vcore and 16 Gib RAM)

When i create the spark shell with the following command `spark-shell --num-executors=6 --executor-cores=5 --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1G --executor-memory 1G --driver-memory 1G`

i see that 6 executors including a driver are being created with 5 cores for each executor for a total of 25 cores

[image: Spark UI executor core count]

However the metrics from hadoop history server does not reflect the right calculations [image: hadoop history server]

I am very confused how in spark UI , more cores than available were allocated for each executor . The total vcores in the cluster is 8 cores considering the core nodes but a total of 25 executors are allocated for the executors.

Can someone please explain what i am missing.

Comment: Does your `spark-shell` use `--master=yarn`?

Comment: i checked and spark.master is `yarn`

Comment: Strange. I guess next thing is to check driver log for messages like `yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 6 executor container(s), each with X core(s) and XXXX MB memory...` and see what kind of containers YARN actually allocated.

Comment: i see the below logs

```22/10/18 21:03:25 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 6, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
22/10/18 21:03:25 INFO YarnAllocator: Will request 6 executor container(s), each with 5 core(s) and 2048 MB memory (including 1024 MB of overhead)
22/10/18 21:03:25 INFO YarnAllocator: Submitted 6 unlocalized container requests.```

Comment: And then? Do you see `ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor N has registered (new total is N)` for N 1 thru 6? Before that, do you see your node manager  in `YarnAllocator: Launching container container_e000_000000000000_000000_01_00000x on host your.host.your.domain for executor with ID N`?